# React: this.props.posts.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I make todo app with React.js + Redux.

But, I have occurs error "TypeError: this.props.posts.map is not a function"

My App.js :

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input />
      <List posts={this.props.allPosts} />
    </div>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    allPosts: state
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(App);
```

My List component :

```
class List extends Component {
  render() {
   console.log(this.props.posts);
   return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (
         <Item {...post} key={index} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My reducer :

```
const initialState = [];

export default function Post(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case ADD_POST:
     return [
     ...state,
     {
      id: action.id,
      title: action.title,
      content: action.content
     }
   ];
```

Why does the error occur?
I set console.log, but it is undefined ...

----EDIT

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/x91zl9v78p

Comment: Please, post a whole code of List component, not just `render` part.

Comment: @amankkg Okay, I edit post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `default` branch in your `switch` statement in your reducer, which will make it so `undefined` is returned by default.

You could add a `default` branch that just returns the state.

```
const initialState = [];

export default function Post(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POST:
      return [
      ...state,
      {
        id: action.id,
        title: action.title,
        content: action.content
      }
    ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You must also make sure that you give `state.post` as `allPost`, and not the entire Redux state. There is also no need for you to use `connect` on the `Item` component because you give the `title` and `content` as props anyway.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    allPosts: state.post
  };
};
```

Comment: Link to sources can be added https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/f16a5d455d1d3cc839c1b2f8087433f89d85ad48/src/createStore.js#L261

Comment: @ko_ma Then please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so we can take a look.

Comment: @ko_ma All the files are empty for me, and the index file is the standard file instead of your index file.

Comment: @Tholle I change all file. sorry

Comment: @Tholle Thank you sir! But, I have a question, Why you delete mapStateToProps from item.jsx and Why this.props.title? not this.props.post.title?

Comment: @ko_ma I try to explain that in the last part of my edited answer. Since you give `title` and `content` as props to `Item`, you don't need to connect it to the store.